# Select data table row based on column with comma separated values

Tags: c#, datatable

I have a data table that contains one column with comma separated values. I am trying to formulate a filter to use with dt.Select and need some help.

Data table looks something like this:

```
col1 | col2 | Some_IDs | col4
-----|------|----------|------
  a  |  b   | 1,2,3    | g
  c  |  d   | 2        | h
  e  |  f   | 1, 3     | i
```

If I am looking for "2", I need rows 1 and 2 returned; if I am looking for 1,3 I need rows 1 and 3 returned.

Thanks.

Comment: what have you actually tired besides displaying a depiction of your data structure? have you performed a google search on the DataTable.Select or how do do Filtering when using a Datatable..?

Comment: Yes I have. I tried "in (...)" and using % but couldn't get it to work. I know better than to just jump in and ask for help without trying to sort it out myself first!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you can use Linq then the following should work:

```
// string filter = can be: "2" , "1,3", etc
var filterArray = filter.Split(',').Select(s => s.Trim());
DataRow[] dataRows = dt.AsEnumerable()
    .Where(row=>filterArray.All(f=>row.Field<string>("Some_IDs")
                                 .Split(',')
                                 .Any(v=>v.Trim() == f)))
    .ToArray();
```

The Above will match the rows that contain *all* filter values.

If you want to rows that matches some of the filter values then use `filterArray.Any` instead of `.All`

```
.Where(row=>filterArray.Any(f=>row.Field<string>("Some_IDs")
                                 .Split(',')
                                 .Any(v=>v.Trim() == f)))
```

Comment: you should replace the `"1,3"` with an actual variable based on what the OP has stated.. this way they won't have to rely on hard-coding

Comment: While I agree, I feel like if OP wants to do that, then they will, it's not the answerer's job to write the exact code that the OP needs, it's our job to point in the right direction, not fine tune our answers to be exactly what the OP needs.

Comment: This works if I search for 2, then it returns rows 1 and 2; but if I search for 1,2 it returns first row only, not the second row which also contains a 2.It is sort of an "OR" operation, if the column contains any of the search numbers(1 or 2 or 1,2), it should match.

Comment: Ok, i thought it should match all of them. Updated my answer